# How can I combine rows in a pandas dataframe based on comparing values in two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a pandas dataframe like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['001', '001', '002', '002', '003', '003', '004', '004', '005', '005'], 
                      'start': [1, 200, 200, 1, 1, 200, 200, 1, 1, 1000],
                      'end': [1000, 500, 500, 1000, 500, 1000, 1000, 500, 500, 2000]})
or 
    id  start   end
0  001      1  1000
1  001    200   500
2  002    200   500
3  002      1  1000
4  003      1   500
5  003    200  1000
6  004    200  1000
7  004      1   500
8  005      1   500
9  005   1000  2000
```

I would like to end up with a pandas dataframe such that if the starts and ends produce overlap for a row with a given id, then they are combined. (Indices are unimportant, here.) Is there a clever or efficient way to do this without resorting to a lot of complicated iteration? (My actual data may have up to millions of rows.)

The end result from the example above should be:

```
   id  start   end
  001      1  1000
  002      1  1000
  003      1  1000
  004      1  1000
  005      1   500
  005   1000  2000
```

Comment: In your example, you always have exactly two rows for every ID. Is that always the case?

Comment: No, it could be more complex. I probably should have had an example like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to do this could be grouping by the id column and then applying a function to merge intervals:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Load or create the dataframe df.

def merge_intervals(group):
    l = zip(group['start'], group['end'])
    merged = []
    for i in sorted(l):
        if not merged or merged[-1][1] < i[0]:
            merged.append(list(i))
        else:
            merged[-1][1] = max(merged[-1][1], i[1])
    start, end = zip(*[(x[0], x[1]) for x in merged])
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'id':    group['id'][0],
        'start': start,
        'end':   end
    })

df_new = df.groupby(df['id'], as_index=False).apply(merge_intervals)
```

In your example, the output looks like this

```py
      id  start   end
0 0  001      1  1000
1 0  002      1  1000
2 0  003      1  1000
3 0  004      1  1000
4 0  005      1   500
  1  005   1000  2000
```

A MultiIndex DataFrame is created, and it will have the same columns.

Thanks to @scott-boston for noticing the error, and @henry-yik for its answer.

Comment: I don't think this work for the id 005 which should remain two separate records.

Comment: @ScottBoston: Yes, thank you for noticing. I think it is corrected now. Somehow I missed that line in the test.

Comment: Nice! That works like a charm. TIL MultiIndex Dataframes. Thank you!

Comment: Something to be aware of, for reasons that are unclear to me, if the id is not found in the df in ascending order, matching up with the index, then you get a KeyError. For my purpose, sorting and then resetting the index with drop=True prior to the groupby fixes it and gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a function to merge the intervals and then `groupby` and `apply`:

```
def merge(l):
    l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0])
    merged = []
    for i in l:
        if not merged or merged[-1][1] < i[0]:
            merged.append(i)
        else:
            merged[-1][1] = max(merged[-1][1], i[1])
    return merged

print (df.groupby("id").apply(lambda d: merge(d[["start","end"]].values)).explode())

id
001       [1, 1000]
002       [1, 1000]
003       [1, 1000]
004       [1, 1000]
005        [1, 500]
005    [1000, 2000]
dtype: object
```